# Error querying COM interfaces - class not registered

Tags: c#, .net, com, regasm

I try to register a COM component in new Windows Server 2012 R2 with `REGASM` and don't get any errors. However, the COM class doesn't get registered.

[Regasm result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS73V.png)

On my developer computer, this class is registered successfully. I don't understand what is going wrong on this server, because I made COM components for years, hundreds of times.

Usually I mark interface in the same way

```
 <Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(True)>
 <Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("65E58463-DB6F-421A-8DE4-A2CE106A7554")>
 <Runtime.InteropServices.InterfaceType(Runtime.InteropServices.ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>
```

And mark implemented class as

```
 <Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(True)>
 <Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("8421A6EE-9101-4119-9262-556B6A45D28B")>
 <Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterface(Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)>
 <Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("TDS.DbMail")>
```

This class I wrote with .NET Framework 4.8, it installed on the server successfully. Attempt to change 32/64 version of library is not successful, either.

Can anybody share any advice with me?

Comment: Use the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe, stored in the Framework64 directory.

Comment: Use `regasm mydll.dll /codebase`. If this doesn't work use a tool such as Process Monitor from sysinternals and scan file and registry accesses

Comment: Thank you HansPassant and Simon Mourier. Finally COM object registered on current server with /codebase and with X64 framework and maybe most important - with strong name signed assembly.